# How to change the color of fixed navigation links when it reaches a certain section?

Tags: jquery, html, colors, navigation

I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the links in my fixed navigation (placed on the side of the page) when it reaches a certain section on the page (because the background of that section is the same color as the links in my navigation).

I am a jQuery newbie, so I don't really know how to go about this. I tried this, naively thinking it might work (but, as you guessed it, it didn't):

```
if ($('.fixednav').offset().top == $('.intro-section').offset().top) {
    $('.fixednav a').css('color', '#ececef');
}
```

If anyone could give me a hint, I'd be really grateful!

Comment: Your Javascript looks like it only works if the page is scrolled down an exact number of pixels, is that the intention? For instance, it might work if you scroll down 407 pixels, but not if 406 or 408 pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have not added `html` part of your code and there is no `jsfiddle` provided also it is hard to answer exactly as per your need. Below is the code you can use to understand the modifications that can be applied in your actual code to get the color changing links

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cnqz/1/), but it does not contains explanation so please read the comments in the javascript code below

**html**

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="link1"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li id="link2"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li id="link3"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li id="link4"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

**css**

```
*{
  margin:0;
}

#nav {
     position: fixed;
     list-style-type: none;
}

#nav a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: orange;
}

#a{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: lightgreen 
}

#b{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange; 
}

#c{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: purple
 }
```

**script**

```
var b=$('#b').offset(); 
var c=$('#c').offset();


$(window).scroll(function(){

/*The same colored region `(orange div with id="b")` is reached and we are still
inside that region not below it that is not in purple region, for this the if 
condition block is used. This condition will also recolor the link when we
scroll towards top from purple (below) to orange (same colored) region */

if( $(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()>=b.top+10 &&
   $(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()<c.top+10 )
{
    $('#link4 a').css('color','green');
}

/*we scroll back from same colored region towards top that is from orange to
lightgreen region*/

else if($(window).scrollTop()<b.top+70)
{
    $('#link4 a').css('color','orange');
}

/* we scroll below the same colored region that is links are to be recolored 
with their original color when we scroll from orange to purple region*/

else if($(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()>=c.top+10)
{
    $('#link4 a').css('color','orange');      
}

/*Same if,else if and else if for other three links*/    

if( $(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()>=b.top+30 &&
    $(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()<c.top+30 )
{
    $('#link3 a').css('color','green');
}

else if($(window).scrollTop()<b.top+50)
{
    $('#link3 a').css('color','orange');
}

else if($(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()>=c.top+30)
{
    $('#link3 a').css('color','orange');      
}


if( $(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()>=b.top+50 &&
    $(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()<c.top+50 )
{
    $('#link2 a').css('color','green');
}


else if($(window).scrollTop()<b.top+30)
{
    $('#link2 a').css('color','orange');
}

else if($(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()>=c.top+50)
{
    $('#link2 a').css('color','orange');      
}


if ( $(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()>=b.top+70 &&
     $(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()<c.top+70 )
{
    $('#link1 a').css('color','green');
}


else if($(window).scrollTop()<b.top+10)
{
    $('#link1 a').css('color','orange');
}

else if($(window).scrollTop()+$('#nav').height()>=c.top+70)
{
    $('#link1 a').css('color','orange');      
}

});
```

**NOTE:-** the position of `ul#nav` is fixed that is why we have to add it's height to `$(window).scrollTop()` to get exact scroll location of window

**Note:-** separate condition sets for each link are used to change the color of a links only when required that is only if `Link 4` is in the orange region the green coloring applied to it only not to the links still in light green region

**feel free to ask doubts, if any**

**EDIT: pasting image ( right click and open in new tab to view full size ) in response to comment for explaining the importance of numbers `10,30..` in code**

[image: Explanation]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly the effect I was looking for! But for some reason, it doesn't work for me, even though I have exactly the same HTML structure - the difference is I have 6 links in my navigation. I think it might have to do with the numbers you are adding—how did you actually come up with these?

Comment: @thosetinydreams i have added an image in the answer to explain what the numbers `10,30,50..` are doing up there in the code. I hope this will clear your doubts.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to feel totally dumb, because for some reason, it doesn't want to work for me. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thosetinydreams/ACrQF/1/) I made with the exact structure I have.

Comment: @thosetinydreams compare `html` and `javascript` from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ACrQF/4/ to your fiddle in comment above..lol :). `id of li(s)` in your code is `#n_intro` it should be like this `n_intro` and you have written Js code only for last two links rest of the code is just a copy paste of the code in answer. Since I am not comfortable with using `%` and calculation was also easy when using `px` I have changed `top:40%` in css to `top:100px` and added extra `105` to `$(window).scrollTop()+$('.fixednav').height()`.

Comment: Omg .. so right now I'm sitting here with a huge facepalm—I have no idea why I put the `#` in the divs in the HTML, seriously. I swear I'm quite bright, usually.. Thank you so much for solving this for me!

Comment: I have this peculiar problem with the color changing menu: it works fine locally, but when I upload it to the server, it changes the color too soon in Google Chrome and IE (in Firefox and Safari, it works just fine). Any idea why it might be doing it?

Comment: @thosetinydreams I am using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.48 m (also checked on version 30.0.x) and IE9 and have checked the page on localhost it is working fine on these browsers IE,Chrome,Safari,Opera,Firefox. Which version of chrome and IE are you using?

Comment: @thosetinydreams However `position type 'fixed'` doesn't work in IE9 or below (don't know about IE 10) so you can put this `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` at the top of your page or you can find other ways on the internet or stack overflow which suits you to make navigation block fix.

Comment: @thosetinydreams have you updated code of your website on server just a moment ago? It was not working properly on first few visits and page refreshes but now it is working. And remove that `console.log('fsdfs')` :)

Comment: No, I haven't touched it at all. And it's still not working :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41121/discussion-between-udb-and-thosetinydreams)

Answer (score 2):

Try [my demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/W7r3v/) mate, your expression were incorrect, use `offset().top and scrolltop()` I gave you various examples of link and background color, you can play around to get what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/W7r3v/

Answer (score 0):

**To add to UDB's answer:**

if content of your website changes when window resized it causes your divs to have new offset. Therefore you have to update your variables to that new offset (in this example those would be b and c ):

```
window.onresize = function(){
    b=$('#b').offset(); 
    c=$('#c').offset();
}
```

This also works for mobile when device is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Godinall answer I have created more dynamic and reusable function.
You can define multiple sections elements classes / id as well as links from navigations.

`JSFiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/djstojadin/twmk1u4v/246/